# excluding a character before a certain character in sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this file that simply prints one line. I'm working on manipulating this one line with different sed commands.

```
apple orange.5678 dog cat 009 you
```

I'm wanting to grab 'orange.5678' and include 'you' and ignore everything else. I want it to look like below

```
orange.5678 you
```

I'm not sure where to start and how to exclude everything except for 'orange.5678' and 'you'. Any help would be great!

Comment: What is the logic that needs to be applied?  Is it based on certain strings or by the column it's in?  We can't guess what you want to do and answering these will move you closer to a solution.

Comment: For starters, how would I exclude the period '.' to get '5678', but not '009'. How would I use the period as a marker to get the stuff I want etc...?

Comment: That is still very far from solving your whole problem.  Work on it and edit the question with the required clarifications.  FYI, `cut -d'.' -f 2` might give you clues on how to do it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/how-do-i-split-a-string-on-a-delimiter-in-bash might also give you other approaches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's/.* ([^ ]+\.[^ ]+).* ([^ ]+)$/\1 \2/' orange
orange.5678 you
```

#### Explanation

- `-r` use extended regular expressions
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`
- `.*` any number of any characters
- `(some characters)` save `some characters` to reference later in replacement
- `[^ ]+` some characters that are not a space
- `\.` literal dot
- `$` end of line
- `\1` backreference to saved pattern

so `s/.* ([^ ]+\.[^ ]+).* ([^ ]+)$/\1 \2/` means, match anything on the line up to a space that precedes some non-space characters up to a `.` and then some non space characters after it (saving those characters either side of the `.`), then match any characters and save the last set of non-space characters on the line, and replace the whole match with the two saved patterns separated by a space

Comment: I am not nitpicking. Just a suggestion. How about adding a `\s` instead of a `space`. Make's it more readable.

Comment: @fossil more readable maybe, but uglier ;)

Comment: Absolutely. I was wondering, if people don't copy paste, they may miss the space. BTW, your regex was inspiring and set's bar for everyone.

Comment: @fossil thanks a lot! I'm just a beginner really :)

Comment: when using mac OS, `-E` is the equivalent for the `-r` flag.

Comment: `-E` works with GNU sed too, so I guess that's the portable way

Answer (score 4):

Simplest approach:

```
awk '{print $2, $6}' file.txt
```

If your actual use case is more complex than your question indicates, and you require additional logic (for example if it's not *always* the 2nd and 6th fields that you need), [**edit your question**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/339039/edit) to clarify.

Comment: Also comment here if you edit your question; I won't get any notification if your question is updated.

Answer (score 1):

**One should look at another answer by @Zanna. Very elegant and shows the power of regular expressions.**

Try this expression with `gawk`. Plain awk won't work with grouping.

```
^(?:\w+\s){0,}(\w+\.\w+)(?:\s\w+){0,}\s(\w+)$
```

It worked for following variations

```
apple orange.5678 dog cat 009 you
apple apple grape.9991 pig cat piegon owl
grape.9991 pig cat piegon owl
```

Here is the description of expression.

```
/
^(?:\w+\s){0,}(\w+\.\w+)(?:\s\w+){0,}\s(\w+)$
/
g
^ asserts position at start of the string

Non-capturing group (?:\w+\s){0,}
{0,} Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

1st Capturing Group (\w+\.\w+)
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\. matches the character . literally (case sensitive)
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Non-capturing group (?:\s\w+){0,}
{0,} Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

2nd Capturing Group (\w+)
\w+ matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
$ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)
```

Comment: This is terrific! Very good explanation! I was struggling with excluding characters after a certain character (in this case a period), but you simplified it. Thank you!

Comment: Let's us know if this worked for you.

Comment: That's a very overcomplicated regex that makes a *lot* of assumptions about the logic required.  And makes *zero* use of Awk's specialty, which is *handling delimited fields.*

Answer (score 0):

If it has to be sed with regex then above answer will cover you.
If you are open to alternatives:

```
gv@debian: $ read -r a b c d e f<<<"apple orange.5678 dog cat 009 you" && echo "$b $f" 
orange.5678 you
```

If this is a line in a file replace `<<<"...."` with `<file`

This method to work requires default IFS = space. If in doube apply `IFS=" "` in the beginning.